# Use wait cursor as mouse pointer in Console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm developing a console application using `c#`. In this application i need to use `dism` command to enable some windows features.

I noticed that in the older versions of dism (previous to the `10.0` version) `dism` doesn't display a loading bar while performing his actions, so the process seems like strucked.

To better inform the user that the process isn't struck but it's working in backgorund, i thought to change the mouse pointer to the wait cursor.

I've tried both this code lines, from other SO questions:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
Application.DoEvents();
```

and

```
Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
```

but the pointer is not changing.

Is possible to change the mouse pointer in a console application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make the cursor turn to the wait cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568557/how-can-i-make-the-cursor-turn-to-the-wait-cursor)

Comment: That question use winforms, i'm asking about a console app. I've stated that i've tried that solution but is not working.

Comment: What about [`Cursor.Current`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568562/542251)? Are firing `DoEvents`? You've tried **one** of those solutions. [There is no difference between console vs windows apps apart from some trivial header information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716292/542251).

Comment: Yes i've tried calling `DoEvents()` too but with no luck. Are those solutions supposed to work in a console app?

Comment: Yes. [*The mouse you want to control is in windows, not the console.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716292/542251)

Comment: No can do.  The console window is owned by a different process (conhost.exe) and there is no winapi function to alter the cursor shape it uses.  Having (almost) no control over that window is by design, conhost.exe acts as a security barrier so nobody can mess with that window.

Comment: @HansPassant -- Not that it'd be worth it, but couldn't you subclass the window returned by `GetConsoleWindow` and work some magic? Like what they are doing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345232/handling-drag-and-drop-files-in-a-running-windows-console-application