# Hide Mouse Cursor in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console, hide, mouse, mouse-cursor

**Cursor.Hide() in Console App**

Sup

Is it possible to hide **mouse** cursor in .Net Framework C# Console Application?
Visual Studio Community 2019 .Net Framework 4.8

I've added a link to System.Windows.Forms

I'm making a console game and I'm using Cursor.Position.X and Cursor.Position.Y to move a camera
But i don't need this *damn* cursor on my screen

Edit:

My question is still open..
Any "Cursor.Current = Cursors.None" or "Custom" (or "Wait" or something else.. does not matter) is not working.
Could anyone help me? Better be if you place a piece of code that already tested in Console Application (Not a Win Forms App)

And BTW I can't "trap" the cursor somewhere because I use it movements to move the camera

Comment: Have you tried `Cursor = Cursors.None`?

Comment: [I don't think you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391615/use-wait-cursor-as-mouse-pointer-in-console-application#comment99384482_56391615).

Comment: First, set cursor to "Custom" and choose an empty ".cur" file. Then use "ClipCursor" API method and trap the cursor to (0,0,0,0). https://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ClipCursor.html

Comment: @yosef-bernal I have not "None" in "Cursors" and thing like "Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor"does not work at my console app actually and I don't know why

Comment: cihan-yakar Could you give an exaple code? I have not "Custom" in "Cursors"

Answer (score 0):

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int X, int Y);
```

Call this method in main string args as

```
SetCursorPos(2000, 2000);
```

this will move real mouse cursor pointer to right corner (invisible mode) until user move the mouse